# Databound Windows Forms control does not recognize change until losing focus

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I use data binding to display values in text boxes in a C# Windows Forms client. When the user clicks Save, I persist my changes to the database. However, the new value in the active editor is ignored (the previous value is saved). If I tab out of the active editor, and then Save, the new value is persisted, as expected.

Is there a way to force the active control to accept its value before persisting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can get the [`Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.aspx) instance that corresponds to the input (the [`TextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.aspx)), you can call the [`WriteValue` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.writevalue.aspx) to force the value from the control to the object it is bound to.

Also, you can call the [`EndCurrentEdit` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingmanagerbase.endcurrentedit.aspx) on the [`BindingManagerBase` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7he0a7s1) (usually a [`CurrencyManager` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager.aspx) instance) to finish the edit, but that requires implementation of the [`ICancelAddNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icanceladdnew.aspx) or [`IEditableObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.aspx) interface on the object that is bound to (and wouldn't require you to fish for the binding).

Answer (score 3):

The solution I've used is to call `ValidateChildren` on the Form from the Save event (call), before actually saving the database records. This forces validation of all fields and thus binding to occur without losing focus of the control currently being edited on the form. It is real handy if the save button is on the Windows menu system and not form itself - plus it returns False if data in any control on the form is invalid and thus can be used to prevent saving errant data.

This also gets around inconsistent updating of the bound field that occurs when `OnPropertyChanged` is used as a binding method instead of `OnValidation`. Also, it is critical if the binding method is set to Never with separate WriteValue calls made for each validated event trapped per control.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of a hack, but try setting the focus away from the active editor (by setting the focus to something else, like the save button for example) in the button event before you call save.